# Dropdown - One option selected not more than one time

Tags: javascript

When i enter a value in Amount tendered input filed, then i chose one the of payment type for instance Cash as payment. it works perfectly.
same thing if i chose Credit Card as payment.

THE PROBLEM
Now if i enter a new value in Amount tendered input filed and chose Cash payment or credit as payments which cash already exits.. it adds new payment as cash or credit...

All i need, if cash payment was selected, then i could added it not more than one time same thing for Credit Card payment.. How to solve this out...
either payment cash selected or credit was selected one time. for each payment

Any help would be thankful.

Code Snippet included down below as well jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cy2zwxpL/

```
    <span id="amount_tendered_label">Grand total</span> 

<input id="Grandtotal" value="1500.00" class="form-control" disabled=""><br/><br/>

<span id="amount_tendered_label">Amount Tendered:</span>

    <input id="amount_tendered" placeholder="0.00" value="" name="amount_tendered" class="form-control">   <br/><br/>   

<span>Payment Type:</span>

<select id="paymenttype" name="paymenttype" class="form-control">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
  <option value="Credit">Credit Card</option>
</select>                                                        

<div id="theading" style="display:none;">
 <span style="width: 1%;">#</span>
 <span style="width: 1%;">Type</span>
 <span style="width: 3%;">Amount</span>
</div>

 <form id="toinvoice" action="" method="post" style="display:hidden" target="_blank">

 <input  type="hidden" name="cash" value="">
 <input  type="hidden" name="credit" value="">

 <div id="payment_contents" style="display:none;">

 </div>
 </form>






$(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#paymenttype').blur(function(event) {
        var Grandtotal      = $('#Grandtotal').attr('value');

        var paymentContents = $('#payment_contents');
        var theading        = $('#theading');
        var amountPaid      = $('#amount_tendered').val();
        var removePaid      = $("input[name='amount_tendered']");
        var dataCash        = $("input[name='cash']");
        var dataCredit      = $("input[name='credit']");

        var option = $(this).children("option").filter(":selected").text();
        if(!option.trim()){

        } else {

            if(option === 'Cash' && dataCash.val() == '') {
                if(amountPaid == '' && dataCash !== '') return ;
                var output = '';
                    output +='<tr>';
                    output +='<td> x </td>';
                    output +='<td>Cash</td>';
                    output +='<td><i class="fa fa-rouble sm"></i>'+amountPaid+'.00'+'</td>';
                    output +='</tr>';
                // appending output
                paymentContents.append(output);

                dataCash.val(amountPaid);

                removePaid.attr('value', '0.00');
                // showing thead 
                theading.show();
                // showing tbody
                paymentContents.show();
                return;
            }
            else  {
                if(amountPaid == '' && dataCredit !== '') return ;
                var output = '';                                                

                    output += '<tr>';
                    output += '<td> x </td>';
                    output += '<td>Credit</td>';
                    output += '<td> <i class="fa fa-rouble sm"></i>'+amountPaid+'.00'+'</td>';
                    output += '</tr>';

                paymentContents.append(output);
                dataCredit.val(amountPaid);
                removePaid.attr('value', '0.00');
                paymentContents.show();
                theading.show();

            }

        }
    });



});
```

Comment: I can't try your jsFiddle. If I type in e.g. "123.00" as value for the 'Amount tendered' and select 'Cash' as payment type, the box only turns to light-yellow and nothing else happens?

Comment: And you don't even have a well-formed HTML, maybe that's why it is not working. You have a "td" without even having it inside a table.

Comment: it works fine.. i have got to remove HTML tags so you guys can read less code rather than unnecessary tags and inputs so you can figure it out

Comment: Ok so then I don't know why it isn't working for me. Maybe my browser doesn't really understand that HTML from you?

Comment: ok check this out again. i have made some modification now it works fine :)

Comment: *payment_contents* is a div element, but you are appending a TR to it. What should the result of that be? What is the point of `if(!option.trim())`?